# JAVA encode/decode base 64 and render it on browser or save it to file

Tags: java, image, base64, decode, encode

I am sending an image after base64 encoding from my JSP to a servlet using AJAX. At the servlet side, I am trying to decode and save it to either a file or render to a browser. 
I am getting an empty image. Here is my servlet side code

```
 String imageStr = request.getParameter("image");
 byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(imageStr);

  String path = "D:\\myImage.png";
    try {
    OutputStream out1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
        out1.write(decoded);
    } finally {


    }
```

I get a the image, but its empty.

Comment: Surely you've made sure that `image` isn't empty? Perhaps you should look into MultiPart, eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269997/file-or-image-uploading-using-java-servlet-with-apache-commons-library

Comment: I print the image string and I see all the crazy characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try closing the stream, it should flush all buffered data:

```
String imageStr = request.getParameter("image");
byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(imageStr);

String path = "D:\\myImage.png";
OutputStream out1 = null;

try {
    out1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
    out1.write(decoded);            
} finally {
    if (out1 != null) {
        *out1.close();*
    }
}
```

And make sure the `decoded` array really contains some data.

Comment: In case something goes wrong in the try block (such as `out1.write()` exceptioning), you should always close resources in a finally block (AKA: Move the `close` line two lines lower).

Comment: This kind of helped. I get a 5 kb image , but there is just a red X in the center of the supposed image.

Comment: In that case the image URL is probably wrong, or the server doesn't return it. It seems like a different issue now.